# How to check for duplicate email entries while registering new users in zend framework 3

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-validate, zend-framework3

I want to duplicate email validation to registration page.For now the following validation is implemented on email.

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'email',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                     'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            $isEmpty => 'Email can not be empty.',
                         ),
                     ),
                    'break_chain_on_failure' => true
                 ),
                 array(
                     'name' => 'EmailAddress',
                     'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                            $invalidEmail => 'Enter Valid Email Address.'
                        )
                    )
                )
              )
             )
          );
```

Comment: You would need to create a custom validator to query the database for the email. If you find one matching, the validator should return false, otherwise true. If you are using Doctrine entities, there is an already existing [`ObjectExists` validator](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/validator.md#use-together-with-zend-framework-2-forms) you can use.

Comment: If you're working with the `TableGateWay` either inject your table into the inputFilter and create a [callback validator](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.validator.callback.html) handling the validation in there or create your custom validator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you do not want the email to be duplicated.

You can add the `Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists` validator :

```
    'validators' = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'NotEmpty',
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                $isEmpty => 'Email can not be empty.',
            ),
        ),
        'break_chain_on_failure' => true
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'EmailAddress',
        'options' => array(
            'messages' => array(
                $invalidEmail => 'Enter Valid Email Address.'
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Zend\Validator\Db\NoRecordExists',
        'options' => array(
            'table' => 'your_table_name',
            'field' => 'email',
            'adapter' => 'your_db_adapter'
        )
    )
)
```

You should not forget to inject your `$db_adapter` into your form.